# Form > Planner Task - Adding to all buckets when only 1 required

Tags: dynamics-365, power-automate

I'm building a Flow task which takes the inputs from a form and adds a planner task based on the information entered. When the planner task is added, it is adding one copy to each bucket. I only want it to add to the bucket nominated in the form. I am already attempting to extract the Bucket ID based on the Bucket Name but I seem to be doing something wrong. Please can somebody point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. Very basic error. The "Apply to each 3" section should have appeared directly below "compose" in the same block. The way it is positioned in the screenshot causes it to execute both if the condition is or is not met.